# How do I recover files from my Windows 7 VirtualBox partition?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, vmware

I have Windows Vista Installed on my laptop.

I ran and created a virtual OS from VMware. Inside that OS, I created 2 partitions and stored the files on the second drive.

Now my Windows 7 installed in VirtualBox has been corrupted and needs to be repaired. VirtualBox itself is not corrupted, but the Windows 7 that runs *in* VirtualBox is. Instead of repairing, I only want to get my data from this second partition.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Boot a livecd on the virtual machine, and copy off the files. If the filesystem itself is damaged, then run some form of repair or recovery software like testdisk. You can also directly mount a vmdk with [vmware diskmount](http://www.vmware.com/download/eula/diskmount_ws_v55.html) - refer to [the manual here](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/VMwareDiskMount.pdf) for detailed instructions but the command should be in the form of 
`vmware-mount [driveletter:] [path-to-vmdk] [options]` - then you can run chkdsk or some recovery software off windows, and/or copy off the files.